# Call a Aurelia function from <script>

Tags: javascript, aurelia

In my Aurelia view I have a **script** tag from where I want to call a function from my view-model:

*Page.html:*

```
<template>
...
  <script>
        function beginEdit(args) {
            console.log(args);
            console.log(args.primaryKeyValue);
            //In this place I want to call the sayHello() fuction
        };
    </script>
</template>
```

*Page.js:*

```
import {inject} from 'aurelia-framework'
import {HttpClient} from 'aurelia-http-client';
import {Router} from 'aurelia-router';

export class Licigrid{
    constructor(){...}           
    activate(){...}
    ...
    sayHello()
    {
        alert("Hello");
    }  
}
```

I tried to use inside my script tag `${sayHello();}` but this calls the function immidiately when the page has loaded and not when the user has entered in the **beginEdit()** function.

I have reproduced this piece of code in [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/wINnKhUtzW0VmPqNbntV?p=preview).

Note that I am using a package that calls the beginEdit function by itself, so unfortunately I can not use .trigger(), .delegate(), or .call() inside my html tag which would solve my problem.

My question is: is there a solution to call the **sayHello()** function from my script tag?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `beginEdit` function needs access to the `App` view model instance.  We can use Aurelia's DI container to retrieve this:

```js
var app = container.get(App);
app.sayHello();
```

Problem is we don't have access to the container within the `beginEdit` function.  We can use a small hack to access the container:

```js
var container = document.body.aurelia.container;
```

We also need the `App` constructor function because it's the key to retrieving the app instance from the container.  We can use the System loader to load the module containing the App constructor function:

```js
System.import('app').then(function(module) {
  var App = module.App;
});
```

All together it looks like this:

```js
function beginEdit() {
  System.import('app').then(function(module) {
    var App = module.App, // get the constructor function
        container = document.body.aurelia.container, // get the container
        app = container.get(App);  // get the instance of App (the viewmodel)
    app.sayHello();
  });
}
```

Here's the working plunkr:
http://plnkr.co/edit/9c0oJmifjW5pXXdD06Hg?p=preview

Comment: Thanks! This works fine, but sometimes needs much time to execute the function and data binding does not work if you are not in app.html/js. I am using Traceur(not Babel) if it worth.

Comment: What needs a lot of time to execute?

Comment: I make in my function a HTTP Request via `client.createRequest()` and then I handle the data. Generally it takes less then one second but sometimes it needs 4-5 secons(rare more). The same problem I have faced with another function that contains few DOM manipulation with jQuery. I need to handle these in aurelia in order to I will be able to use validation and HTTP-client. `validation.validate()` does not work too with container. These all(data binding too) work without any issues with `.trigger` but unfortunately I can not use this every time as I mentioned in question.

Comment: Why not make the request from your view model?  I'm unclear on why the script tag is needed

Comment: I was not clear enough, excuse me. So in the view I am having a grid(using with a package) and then I have to define some function that will be fired automatically by the package when some specific events will be fired. When the event have fired the package calls the function in the view and from that I want to call a function from view-model. I am making the request and the validation in the view-model, not in the model. Concretely I want to step into view-model from model. The HTML part of the grid is builded by the package.

Comment: Ok- I think we need to discontinue the discussion here- we'll hit the comment limit soon.  Please consider posting a new question that explains what you want to do at a higher level- "how to use grid xyz with Aurelia and handle grid event abc" or something like that.  I think you might have gotten started in the wrong direction and if we back up a little bit we can arrive at a more natural implementation.